# Windows 11 keeps changing my background back to default every few minutes

Tags: windows, background-image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBwFA.png)
My computuer will set the background image to default every few minutes.
The yellow one in recent images show how many times it set my background.

I've turn off remember my preferences in windows backup, it doesn't work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about programming, so it's not on-topic on Stack Overflow (see [help/on-topic] to learn about what is on-topic and what isn't). The right place to ask this is probably [su] or some Windows forum.

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn on remember my preferences from settings and then turn off the change wallpaper timer